# benchmarking function called inside a module in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a Julia module containing two functions as follows:

```
module SetupMod


export SetupProblem


Base.@kwdef struct MatParams
    E::Float32
    ν::Float32
    ρ::Float32
    ConstModelType::Char = 'E' #E= Elastic and V=von Mises Plastic
end


Base.@kwdef struct MeshParams
    NumElsX::UInt32 = 1
    NumElsY::UInt32 = 1
    LenY::Float32 = 0.
    LenX::Float32 = 0.
end


Base.@kwdef struct AnalysisConsts
    LoadStpsNum::UInt32
    g::Float16 = 10.
    NumMP::UInt8 #Number of material point per direction per element
    MPType::Char = 'M' #M = MPM and G=GIMP
    
end


function Compute2DGrid(T, MeshParams)
    NEls::UInt32 = MeshParams.NumElsX * MeshParams.NumElsY
    NNodes::UInt32 = (MeshParams.NumElsX + 1)* (MeshParams.NumElsY + 1)
    NodeCoords = zeros(T, (NNodes, 2))
    Size = size(NodeCoords)
end


function SetupProblem(T)
    # MatConst = MatParams(E=1e4, ν = 0., ρ = 80., ConstModelType='E')
    ModelConst = MeshParams( NumElsX = 1, NumElsY = 32, LenY = 50., LenX = 50/32)
    AnalysisConst = AnalysisConsts(LoadStpsNum = 40, g = 9.81, NumMP=2, MPType='M')
    Compute2DGrid(T, ModelConst)
end


end # module
```

I want to know the time to run Compute2DGrid() function when I call SetupProblem() function as below:

```
using .SetupMod
using BenchmarkTools
SetupMod.SetupProblem(Float32)
```

When I add @btime in front of Compute2DGrid function call, the IDE is opening a file called execution.jl and giving an exception. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `using BenchmarkTools` statement should be inside the `SetupMod` module since that's the scope in which you are using `@btime`.

Whichever editor you are using as your IDE (VS Code/Juno), it's probably trying to show you an `UndefVarError: @btime not defined` since `@btime` isn't available in that scope.